# How can I edit the Calendars shown on the Mac notification sidebar?

Tags: calendar, notifications, google-calendar

In my Calendar App on the Mac I can see all my Google, iCloud and Mac calendars. This is great. In the sidebar (Notification area), the Calendar widget does not display the full events especially of the other Calendars. I have many events happening today but only showing one?

Is there a way to show all my Calendar events in this window? Picture below.

I am using Mojave on a MacBook Pro.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried removing and re-adding the Calendar Widget in the Notification Center?  Have you ensured the calendars' boxes are checked in the left side of Calendar.app?

Comment: Yes I have tried all this.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to open the settings of the calendar?
**Calendar** > **Preferences...** > **Account**

- [x] Enlable this account

[image]

Comment: Yes I have tried this